# Guice.createInjector error

Tags: eclipse-rcp, guice, mybatis

I'm trying to use mybatis-guice in eclipse 4 rcp project:

```
injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyBatisModule() {
        @Override
        protected void initialize() {
        install(JdbcHelper.HSQLDB_Embedded);
        bindDataSourceProviderType(PooledDataSourceProvider.class);
        bindTransactionFactoryType(JdbcTransactionFactory.class);
        addMapperClass(UserMapper.class);
        Names.bindProperties(binder, createTestProperties());
        bind(FooService.class).to(FooServiceMapperImpl.class);
        }
        });
```

and getting exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mybatis.guice.AbstractMyBatisModule.bindInterceptor(Lcom/google/inject/matcher/Matcher;Lcom/google/inject/matcher/Matcher;[Lorg/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor;)
```

what i'm doing wrong?